# What's a fast way to find rows that have been recently updated?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of webpages which I periodically crawl (because the webpages periodically change), and I keep track of when the page was first discovered, and when it was last updated. The table design is approximately:

```
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+
| id     | url     | discovered | last_updated | title   | text    |
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+
| int    | varchar | datetime   | datetime     | varchar | varchar |
+--------+---------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+
```

Right now I'm only indexing the id and url (actually, the SHA1 hash of the URL to be precise). However, I periodically want to look up the "most recent" articles. I.e., those which have been updated within the last N seconds (N is usually the number of seconds in a day).

The trouble is that query is starting to get slow as the table grows. I was wondering what the right solution to this problem was? I could index last_updated, or perhaps I could create a new table which keeps track of the last_updated times for each webpage. E.g., create this secondary table:

```
+--------+------------+--------------+
| id     | webpage_id | last_updated |
+--------+------------+--------------+
```

Then I can keep track of the mapping from id to last_updated in this new table and do:

```
select webpage_id from LastUpdatedTable where id > (ID_FOR_N_SECONDS_AGO)
```

Or is there a more elegant solution for quickly finding rows which have been updated in the last N seconds?

thanks!

Comment: Can't you just put an index on your `last_updated` and `discovered` columns?

Comment: Aye index on last_updated would help tons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create an index over `last_updated`.

It works very well. No need to spend your time on some custom tracking logic (unless you absolutely have to and know *what* you're doing and *why*).

If you were using [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org), I would recommend to use their [*capped collections*](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections). This is a type of collection made specifically for this kind of operations. You set maximum size for such collection and start writing data. When it is full, oldest entries get overwritten. I don't know if there is a similar feature in MySQL.

You might consider using mongo just to store this small collection of pages and save RAM by not creating index on `last_updated`.